# I want to change header and footer in magento

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am new to magento and self learning. My problem is changing magento default header and footer to my own header and footer. How can i do this???

I dont have any idea about it,
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you remember to google before coming to SO?

Comment: Yes, I did.. But i didnt get clear solution..

Comment: Actually I want to change with images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you can enbale the template path hints to understand exact template used for header and footer.

To turn on template path hints in Magento:

1. log into the magento back-end admin.
2. Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu.
3. Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED.
4. Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.

when you have the access of header and footer template file you will see that whole code is not coming directly from template file. This is also managed from Other modules as well. Those template called like this way:

`echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch')`

For more better Understanding on this you also need to refer layout page.xml for Header and Footer block.

`<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">`

and

`<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">`

Here you will see all the child blocks that are added in Header. Also in Other modules XML Child blocks added in Header and Footer using the `reference` tag as below:

`<reference name="header">`

So you need to check Header and footer Template file and modify using help layout xml file.

Comment: I understood, I have created static blocks and changed in footer, But I want my own design for footer.. I mean adding footer with css styles.

Comment: Thanks for giving me an idea to change it.

Comment: Good point regards enabling template path hints. I didn't know about this feature.

Comment: @pankaj : Is possible can i change header and footer for my second store using with same theme

Answer (score 0):

you can edit phtml file for header: app/design/frontend/your package name/ theme name/page/html/header.phtml
and for footer: app/design/frontend/your package name/ theme name/page/html/footer.phtml

Comment: Is possible can i change header and footer for my second store using with same theme

Comment: get store code in your phtml by $storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode(); and here you can put condition